# My server is running an perfect in local though in Heroku it's throwing not found(404)

Tags: heroku

I am using github repo to deploy my node app in heroku .My server is running an perfect in local though in Heroku it's  throwing not found(404).I guess it's with my static folder that i defined in express.static().

Comment: So! what is your question?

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/Views/index.html'

Comment: @fool-dev, Apologies if my question was not clear.I am facing issue while starting up my server in heroku ,Error am getting in log is                      
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/Views/index.html'         while sending html file to server.   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'public','/','Views', 'index.html'));